# Make multiple parallel axios request in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, asynchronous, parallel-processing, axios

I need to make a progress bar of importing records, which user sends from frontend to server (on spring boot).

The first request is importing to the DB (post request). The second request I use to know about progress of inserting. For this reason I need sometimes send the second request about progress of importing, but I have fail with it.

The problem is that after starting the first request, nothing happens (I see this in the output on the server that the lines were imported and that’s it) the whole interface freezes

I tried to send the second request in insomnia when the first request was sent in the browser and the answer for second request was returned to me. And when I make both requests in parallel in the browser, then no response comes.

Code (React):

```
async sendRecordsToServer() {
    let stateSaved = this;
    const response = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: /*url*/,
        data: JSON.stringify(this.state.selectedData),
        headers: /*headers*/
    });
    const json = await response.data;
    if (json) {
        console.log("response from server 1 request if");
        console.log(json);
        stateSaved.setState({
            countOfImportedRows: json.length
        });
        stateSaved.setState({  
            modalStateShowInfoImport: "show"
        });  
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("response from server 1 request else");
        console.log(json);
        stateSaved.setState({  
            modalStateShowActiveSession: "show"
        }); 
        return false;  
    }
}

async getLastIdInTable() {
    let stateSaved = this;
    const response = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: /*url*/,
        headers: /*headers*/
    });
    const json = await response.data;
    console.log("response from server 2 request");
    console.log(json);
    return json;
}

sleep(time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

async _sendData(){
    const lastIdInTableBeforeImport = await this.getLastIdInTable();
    let countOfAlreadyImportedRows = 0;
    const responseFromImporting = await this.sendRecordsToServer();

    while (countOfAlreadyImportedRows != this.state.data.length) {
        this.sleep(3000).then(async () => {
            const lastIdInTableCurrent = await this.getLastIdInTable();
            countOfAlreadyImportedRows = lastIdInTableCurrent - lastIdInTableBeforeImport;
            console.log("in loop");
            console.log(countOfAlreadyImportedRows);
        }); 
    }
}
```

UPD:

Make some changes in code and add new `console.log()` to show [more details](https://ibb.co/sv9Dr3T).

Code:

```
async _sendData(){
    const lastIdInTableBeforeImport = await this.getLastIdInTable();
    let countOfAlreadyImportedRows = 0;
    const responseFromImporting = this.sendRecordsToServer();
    console.log("after sendRecordsToServer()");
    while (countOfAlreadyImportedRows != this.state.data.length) {
        console.log("before sleep");
        this.sleep(3000).then(async () => {
            console.log("in sleep");
            const lastIdInTableCurrent = await this.getLastIdInTable();
            countOfAlreadyImportedRows = lastIdInTableCurrent - lastIdInTableBeforeImport;
            console.log("in loop");
            console.log(countOfAlreadyImportedRows);
        }); 
    }
}

async sendRecordsToServer() {
    let stateSaved = this;
    const response = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: /*url*/,
        data: JSON.stringify(this.state.selectedData),
        headers: /*headers*/
    });
    // const json = await response.data;
    // if (json) {
    //     console.log("response from server 1 request if");
    //     console.log(json);
    //     stateSaved.setState({
    //         countOfImportedRows: json.length
    //     });
    //     stateSaved.setState({  
    //         modalStateShowInfoImport: "show"
    //     });  
    //     return true;
    // } else {
    //     console.log("response from server 1 request else");
    //     console.log(json);
    //     stateSaved.setState({  
    //         modalStateShowActiveSession: "show"
    //     }); 
    //     return false;  
    // }
}

async getLastIdInTable() {
    let stateSaved = this;
    const response = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: /*url*/,
        headers: /*headers*/
    });
    const json = await response.data;
    console.log("response from server 2 request");
    console.log(json);
    return json;
}

sleep(time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
async _sendData(){ 
   const lastIdInTableBeforeImport = await this.getLastIdInTable();
    let countOfAlreadyImportedRows = 0;
    const responseFromImporting = await this.sendRecordsToServer(); // let's add `await` back, it isn't the murder.
    console.log("after sendRecordsToServer()");

    const timerId = setInterval(()=> {
    if(countOfAlreadyImportedRows !== this.state.data.length) {

       this.getLastIdInTable().then((lastIdInTableCurrent) => {
         countOfAlreadyImportedRows = lastIdInTableCurrent - 
         lastIdInTableBeforeImport;
         console.log("in loop");
         console.log(countOfAlreadyImportedRows);
       })

   }else{
    clearInterval(timerId);
   }

  }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: yes, fix it. But now it stops on: `const responseFromImporting = await this.sendRecordsToServer();` And how can I do the second request `this.getLastIdInTable()` in parallel with the first request `this.sendRecordsToServer();` ?

Comment: If I'm right, it didn't stop. It's promise. When u got promise, u can't expected value through assign. 
Pls check did ur request have been sent or not.

Comment: the problem is that i don't need to stop at `this.sendRecordsToServer();` and with await and without await I stopped in this step and there are not actions after that. I need to send the first request and while it proccessing at the server I need to send the second request about progress og the first.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Suggestion: 
Make a console after `this.sendRecordsToServer()` and make sure remove await before it. According ur description, u want the loop spark. the problem may be not about `this.sendRecordsToServer()` while your condition `countOfAlreadyImportedRows != this.state.data.length`

Comment: [Make](https://ibb.co/X5Y7Ft3) as you suggested and [output](https://ibb.co/PtLcvrY) of it. Now I didn't see output from `lastIdInTableBeforeImport` but it needed because without it I can't calculate how many records already import.

Comment: make some changes (see it on UPD in my question) - the problem is that code freezes before `sleep()` function.

Comment: Yep, thought of it. Your heartbeat code is the problem. I guess your experience from other language is not work in js. In js , your code lead tha stack is filled with timer, aka, `setTimeout`. Of course progress will crash. Let me update my answer.

Comment: My pleasure to help some. U r also doing a great work to help me find out the root cause.